# WildFly dependencies

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, dependencies, wildfly

Plese help me set dependencies in Wildfly.
I have Maven project
Parent:

- Service
- Web

Service is EJB. Web is WAR using utils.jar from Service.ear

**Service.ejb** 
Utils.jar in lib

```
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-ear-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <earName>${project.build.finalName}</earName>
                    <modules>
...
                        <javaModule>
                            <groupId>by.services</groupId>
                            <artifactId>by.utils</artifactId>
                            <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
                        </javaModule>
...
```

Jboss-deployment-strucuture.xml in Web.war

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <!--<ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>-->
    <deployment name="mobile-console.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="by.lib" meta-inf="export" export="true"/>
            <module name="deployment.services-1.0.5.ear.model-core-1.1.jar"/>
            <module name="deployment.services-1.0.5.ear.by.utils-1.0.2.jar"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

So I have error

```
11:58:25,987 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "web.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "module.resolved.service.\"deployment.web.war\".main",
        "jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.services-1.0.5.ear.by.utils-1.0.2.jar\".main"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.web.war\".main is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.services-1.0.5.ear.by.utils-1.0.2.jar\".main, module.resolved.service.\"deployment.web.war\".main]",
        "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.web.war\".main.1 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.mobile.bank.services-1.0.5.ear.by.utils-1.0.2.jar\".main]"
    ]
}
11:58:25,988 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "web.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "module.resolved.service.\"deployment.web.war\".main",
        "jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.services-1.0.5.ear.by.utils-1.0.2.jar\".main"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.web.war\".main is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.services-1.0.5.ear.by.utils-1.0.2.jar\".main, module.resolved.service.\"deployment.web.war\".main]",
        "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.web.war\".main.1 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.services-1.0.5.ear.by.utils-1.0.2.jar\".main]"
    ]
}
11:58:26,001 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment web.war (runtime-name: web.war) in 12ms
11:58:26,002 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.module.service."deployment.web.war".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."web.war".FIRST_MODULE_USE] 
      service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.web.war".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.web.war".main] 
      service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.services-1.0.5.ear.by.utils-1.0.2.jar".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.web.war".main, service jboss.module.resolve.phase."deployment.web.war".main.1] 
      service module.resolved.service."deployment.web.war".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.web.war".main]
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you need the `jboss-deployment-strucuture.xml` file? What version of WildFly are you using?

Comment: Wildfly 10.1.0 jboss-deployment-strucuture.xml - Just my guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to build an EAR file.

You probably already have the

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>by.services</groupId>
   <artifactId>by.utils</artifactId>
   <version>...</version>
</dependency>
```

and the EJB dependency in the pom.xml for your web application.

Just build and deploy the resulting WAR file, *even if you're using EJBs*. Both the dependent jars should finish up in the WAR file's WEB-INF/lib directory.

You don't need any special deployment descriptors and you don't need to know the class visibility rules for modules in EAR files.

Comment: Yes I have it but scope-provided

Comment: Remove the `<scope>provided</scope>` from these two dependencies

Comment: So why do I lay down Utils.jar in the EAR and WAR? Why can not pull out of the EAR?

Comment: Forget about the EAR, you don't need it unless you are planning to put more than one WAR in it and then share the EJBs and Utils.jar.